# React Native Alert doesn't accept Navigation in my code

Tags: react-native, navigation, dialog, alert

I'm trying to add a navigation in this Alert with Dialog, in the 'OK' option to confirm Logout and go back to the login screen, however it's not working. Does anyone help me with this?
I'm also trying to insert a dark theme for the entire application, local expo finger printing and push notifications in setData options 2, 3, and 4, but it's a difficult task as well.. But I'm more focused on creating this Navigation in my Alert because I'm trying.
i'll be very grateful for the help :)
when I grow up, I'm going to be a great programmer.

```
 import { SafeAreaView,Text, View, FlatList,
    TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, Image, Switch, Alert} from 'react-native';
    import { Entypo } from 'react-native-vector-icons';
    import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
    import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
    import * as LocalAuthentication from 'expo-local-authentication';
    
    
    //import Auth from './Biometric'
    
          
        const Settings = () =>{
    
        const [data, setData] = useState([
            { id: 1, text: 'Perfil', image: require('../../assets/images/user.png'), chosen: false },
            { id: 2, text: 'TouchId', image: require('../../assets/images/fingerprint.png'), chosen: false },
            { id: 3, text: 'Dark/Light mode', image: require('../../assets/images/light-up.png'), chosen: false },
            { id: 4, text: 'Notificações', image: require('../../assets/images/bell-fill.png'), chosen: false },
        ]);
    
        const [isRender, setisRender] = useState(false);
    
        const navigation = useNavigation();
    
        const handleLogout = () => {
            //navigation.navigate();
            Alert.alert('Logout!', 'Deseja realmente sair?', [
              {
                text: 'Cancelar',
                onPress: () => {},
              },
        
              {
                text: 'OK',
            onPress:()=>
            {navigation.navigate ("Login")}
        
                },
              
            ]);
        }
    
    
        const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
            
            return (
                
                <TouchableOpacity
                    style={styles.item}
                >
                    <View style={styles.avatarContainer}>
                        <Image source={item.image} style={styles.avatar} />
                    </View>
                    <View>
                        <Text style={styles.text}>{item.text}</Text>
                    </View>
                    {item.id > 1 && <Switch style={{ width: 10, alignItems: 'flex-end',
                    marginTop: 15, flex: 1, marginEnd: 30}}
                        thumbColor={item.chosen == false ? "#CDCDCD" :  "#A0D800"}
                        trackColor={{ true: "#CDCDCD" }}
                
                        value={item.chosen}
                        onChange={() => setData(data.map(index => item.id === index.id
                            ? { ...index, chosen: !index.chosen }
                            : index
                        ))} />}
                        {item.id === 2 
                        
                        }
    
                </TouchableOpacity>
            );
        };
    
    
        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
                <FlatList
                    data={data}
                    keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
                    renderItem={renderItem}
                    extraData={isRender} />
    
            <View style = {{alignSelf: 'center',}}>
                <TouchableOpacity 
                onPress={()=> (handleLogout)}
    
                style = {{borderRadius: 10,
                alignItems: "center",
                backgroundColor: "#A0D800",height: 50, width: 200,
                bottom: 15,
                shadowColor: 'rgba(0,0,0, .4)', // IOS
                shadowOffset: { height: 1, width: 1 }, // IOS
                shadowOpacity: 1, // IOS
                shadowRadius: 1, //IOS
                elevation: 2, // Android
                }}>
                    
                    <Text style={{color: "#ffffff",
                    fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 17,
                    padding: 5, bottom: 0, marginTop: 5,
    
                    }}>
                             SignOut
                    </Text>
                    <Entypo name={'log-out'}
                    style={{alignSelf: 'flex-end', bottom: 25,
                    marginEnd: 25}}
                    color={'#ffffff'}
                    size={20}
                    />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
    
    
            </SafeAreaView>
    
            
            
        );
    
     
    }
          
          const styles = StyleSheet.create({
              container: {
              flex: 1,
              marginTop: 20
              //marginHorizontal: 21
      
              },
              item:{
              borderBottomWidth: 1,
              borderBottomColor: '#808080',
              alignItems: 'flex-start',
              flexDirection: 'row',
        
              },
              avatarContainer: {        
                  backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                  //borderRadius: 100,
                  height: 30,
                  width: 30,
                  justifyContent: 'center',
                  alignItems: 'center',
                      
                },
                
                avatar: {
                  height: 25,
                  width: 25,
                  bottom: -25,
                  marginLeft: 30
                },
              text:{
                  marginVertical: 30,
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: 'bold',
                  marginLeft: 30,
                  marginBottom: 10,
                  bottom: 5
              },  
    
             
          });
          
          export default Settings;
```

Comment: Did you get any errors from it?

Comment: @caslawter isn't showing error in the console, but does not works

Comment: I believe that the error is only in logic

Comment: please some help :(

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is because of your `onPress={()=> (handleLogout)}`. onPress takes in a function but in your case you are making the function run another function, so your alert will not even be activated. To fix this, simply change your code to this.

```
 onPress={handleLogout}
```

Comment: would have any tips for people beginners in programming? Any site that is good to study? Here in Brazil it is difficult to find good sites

Comment: Programming in general or react native?

Comment: I'm only learning react native for now